# FrameLayout IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I'm having this error in a Dialog instantiated from a PreferenceActivity. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
public class NumberPickerPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public static final int MAX_VALUE = 24;
    public static final int MIN_VALUE = 2;

    public NumberPicker picker;
    FrameLayout dialogView;
    private int value;
    Context ctx;


    public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ctx = context;
        dialogView = new FrameLayout(ctx);
        picker = new NumberPicker(ctx);
    }

    public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        picker.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        dialogView.addView(picker); // <- this line has the error

        return dialogView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);
        picker.setMinValue(MIN_VALUE);
        picker.setMaxValue(MAX_VALUE);
        picker.setValue(getValue());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        if (positiveResult) {
            setValue(picker.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return a.getInt(index, MIN_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue, Object defaultValue) {
        setValue(restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedInt(MIN_VALUE) : (Integer) defaultValue);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        persistInt(this.value);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

And this is the stacktrace

```
04-26 00:47:30.870  25385-25385/tk.stayhappy.packagetracker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tk.stayhappy.packagetracker, PID: 25385
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3937)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3787)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3759)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:492)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:236)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:356)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
            at android.preference.DialogPreference.showDialog(DialogPreference.java:294)
            at android.preference.DialogPreference.onClick(DialogPreference.java:274)
            at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:983)
            at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:214)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1148)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3059)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

I have no more ideas as what it could be wrong. Tried changing the context with the ApplicationContext, removing `picker` on dialog dismiss, getting the parents of `picker` and `dialogView` and checking the `childCount`. No luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is `onCreateDialogView` being called more than once?

Comment: The crash only appears when trying to open the dialog for the second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view can only have one parent.  `onCreateDialogView` will return `dialogView`, which will then be added to a view (and thus receive a parent). If `onCreateDialogView` is called a second time, `dialogView` will already have a parent and will throw an `IllegalStateException`.  Instead, initialize `dialogView` and `picker` inside of `onCreateDialogView` so that you start with fresh, parent-less views every time.

Comment: This is how I instantiate my dialog.. NumberPickerPreference numberPickerPreference = new NumberPickerPreference(getApplicationContext(), null);

Doesn't it create another instance of the dialog?.. Is it calling the onCreateDialogView of the previous instance the second time?

Comment: Still crashes my app even after doing what you suggested... :/

Comment: @csanonymus same stack trace?

Comment: Actually, the issue may still be `onCreateDialogView` called twice.  I was thinking `picker` may be the issue, but it might actually be the view returned by `onCreateDialogView`, which is `dialogView`.  After `dialogView` is returned, it too is likely assigned a parent.  Maybe try moving `dialogView` and `picker` initialization into `onCreateDialogView`.

Comment: After moving some code around and moving the initialization of dialogView and picker works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76259/discussion-between-pathfinderelite-and-csanonymus).